# What is the .onebin file in OneNote 2013 cache folder?

Tags: backup, office-365, onenote

I see a lot of .onebin files in OneNote cache folder. As recently I had problems with lost changes in an offline copy I want to know if it's possible to recover information from this files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This take me some time, because on internet I couldn't find information about .onebin extension, but if you go to the unzipped folder OneNoteOfflineCache_Files it contains the binary original files, so you can rename it and use to recover information (knowing the date of creation may help...). In my case I have recovered images as .jpg and some excel (xlsx) files.