# How to recover lost information when working offline in OneNote?

Tags: office-365, offline, onenote, data-recovery

I was working offline in a project when OneNote was frozen (message with "loading..."). When I connected to the network and reopened OneNote it synchronized with the good copy of the "cloud", but all my workday has been lost.

Someone here can help me?

Any idea if I can recover "unsaved changes" as in Excel and Word?

I think my changes should be on any place in my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It take me some time but finally after reading a lot I recovered all my work thanks to the OneNote cache and reapair tool.

Here are the steps to recover lost data:

1. First of all, I made a backup of all the onenote folder from "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneNote\15.0\OneNoteOfflineCache_Files" in a zip. You should do this. Important: You must do it as soon as possible to avoid losing data.
2. Create folder c:\bak and unziped the OnenoteCache Files and Folders (OneNoteOfflineCache.onecache and OneNoteOfflineCache_Files)
3. Rename OneNoteOfflineCache.onecache to OneNoteOfflineCache.one
4. Execute OneNote.exe /forcerepair c:\bak\OneNoteOfflineCache.one and wait to finish
5. Now you can open the file and search for your lost sections/pages. The main issue is that embbeded files like images are not recovered (I'm not tested what happens if you restore from original location of the cache. It may recover images and binary files..)
6. This take me some time, because on internet I couldn't find information [about .onebin extension](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101739/what-is-the-onebin-file-in-onenote-2013-cache-folder?rq=1), but if you go to the unzipped folder OneNoteOfflineCache_Files it contains the binary original files, so you can rename it and use to recover information (knowing the date of creation may help...). In my case I have recovered images as .jpg and some excel (xlsx) files.

Comment: I tried to do this but I get an error in OneNote that the file is from the future.  It seems that my cache is from the previous version of onenote, but I don't have that version any more.  I am attempting to do this because my company switched our accounts but for some reason none of the onenote data was moved over.  So I can't sync to the old account and the only copies I have are on my iPad.  I found the offline cache after googling, but it seems it is useless without the old version of OneNote . . .

Comment: This solution is old... may be somthing has been changed in OneDrive...